# how to add element in django list

Tags: django, list, session

I'm confused with how django adds elements to a list.  consider the following:

```
def add(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)        
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]          
        
            request.session['tasks'].append(task)
            # request.session['tasks'] += [task]
      
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tasks:index"))            
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
                "form": form
            })
    return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
    "form": NewTaskForm()
})
```

if we add a print statement after request.session['tasks'].append(task) we get a list:

```
['check email']
```

we also get the same list if we comment the append line and use the correct way with +=

However, on the redirect to task/index the first way shows an empty list and the second way shows the list that's expected.  Why?  Whats going on?

Comment: Where/how is sessions['tasks'] defined?

Comment: good catch, there's a line missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django only saves the session data and sends to client if it has been assigned or deleted. Like in your second example:

```
request.session['tasks'] += [task]
```

If you are updating the information inside your session data, it will not recognize the change and won't update it, like when you append some data to the list that is assigned to the 'tasks' key. In this case you need to explicitly tell Django that you modified the session data using:

```
request.session.modified = True
```